# How to Show multiple Images in row from Data. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, array-map

My Data Look Like This

```
["https://files-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/61681a7d32ac23af58589eef/CompanyImages/CompanyImages.jpg","https://files-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/61681a7d32ac23af58589eef/CompanyImages/CompanyImages.jpg","https://files-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/61681a7d32ac23af58589eef/CompanyImages/CompanyImages.jpg","https://files-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/61681a7d32ac23af58589eef/CompanyImages/CompanyImages.jpg"]
```

Now I want To Show These 4 images in row

I am Mapping Like this

```
{Data.CompanyImages.map((item) => {
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Image
      style={{
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        marginTop: 1.5,
        borderRadius: 7,
      }}
      source={{uri: item}}
    />
  </View>;
})}
```

but its not showing anything please help

Comment: Are you sure that in the map function, "item" is a uri ? Have you got some console output to provide ?

Answer (score 0):

Open any image of your list in the browser, you can see that there is an error returned, please make sure you set the images to public access in your S3 or adjust your code to pass some params to indicate that the access to those images is valid and the S3 return the content

Check [Your image link](https://files-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/61681a7d32ac23af58589eef/CompanyImages/CompanyImages.jpg)

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
<Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<Bucket>files-bucket</Bucket>
<RequestId>Z72TT83DFD04M8EJ</RequestId>
<HostId>AMuc/KSYXayYgzkigho3CTqNluTLEDAI/EYUug3U4NKsJB8xbnJSDsFn8VlaNZ50N73EAWhi2p0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: I have Change The URL for some personal reasons. just tell me my code is right or not ??

Comment: Based on the documentation [react native images docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image), your code looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `Data` is valid and `Data.CompanyImages` is the array you have shown in your question, then I see two problems in your code.

1. You have to return the `JSX` from your `map` function.
2. Wrap the map function with a View with `flexDirection` = `row`

Change your map to,

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}> // wrap list with flexDirection row
  {Data.CompanyImages.map((item) => ( //returning JSX with ()
    <Image
      style={{
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        marginTop: 1.5,
        borderRadius: 7,
      }}
      source={{uri: item}}
    />
  ))}
</View>
```